# It would create a new process when put a new war package in the tomcat webapps directory?

Tags: java, tomcat, jvisualvm

In IIS with ASP.NET , if there are two applications put in the it, it would create another two standalone w3wp.exe processes.
So how about tomcat with war package? If I put two web1.war and web2.war to the webapps path, it would also create another two processes , or these two war package would just running in the same process as tomcat(share the same process tomcat.exe)?

C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\web1.war

C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\web2.war

From the task manger, I also cannot see the process Java.exe or Javaw.exe process.
[image]

Comment: The second. The behavior is fully specified by the [servlet lifecycle](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafi.html) (see also [JSR-154](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=154)) and their are multiple implementations besides Tomcat.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @Elliott , so it means all of the war packages share the same process tomcat.exe?

Comment: @Andreas , the issue is if all of the war packages share the same process tomcat.exe , how to monitor the special war by the visualVM , support I just want to monitor the war1 and not the war2?

Comment: @Elliott, however I  cannot see the process Java.exe or Javaw.exe process. please see the snapshot in the question

Comment: Do you see `tomcat.exe`?

Comment: @Andreas , Yes, I can see the tomcat.exe, however cannot see the Java.exe or Javaw.exe.

Comment: Because `tomcat.exe` is the Tomcat process. @ElliottFrisch was mistaken in his expectation. But to answer to comment question "how to monitor the special war by the visualVM": You can't, unless you run them in two different Tomcat instances.

Comment: @ Andreas , you mean all of the war share the same process tomcat.exe? and suppose if one of the war has the memory leak issue, then I just need to capture the core dump for the process tomcat.exe, am I right?

Comment: @Andreas ,I found the following URL, does it mean I can monitor one special appl in tomcat container?    https://visualvm.java.net/jmx_connections.html      
=================================================================                                                                            

java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=3333 \
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
     YourJavaApp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123906/discussion-between-jason-and-andreas).

Comment: If you're looking for a memory leak, you should definitely start a dedicated Tomcat for the app you're researching.

Comment: @Andreas ，I  found if I start the tomcat through Windows Service, then the process is tomcat.exe, however if I started it by startup.bat , then then process become to Java.exe ,  can you help to confirm it ?

Comment: Sure, if that's what you see.

Comment: @Andreas, Thank you for your confirmation.